# Example using fork() in Gnu-Octave

Tags: multithreading, fork, octave

As the help text to the `fork()` function is not very comprehensive, i would be interested in a working example of this function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Complete examples can be seen in the source for some Octave packages. See for example, [parcellfun](http://hg.code.sf.net/p/octave/parallel/file/90310deab8fc/inst/parcellfun.m#l147) and [__bw_scheduler__](http://hg.code.sf.net/p/octave/parallel/file/88782b544098/inst/__bw_scheduler__.m#l129) (from the parallel package), [jacobs](http://hg.code.sf.net/p/octave/optim/file/0ade18b6cde4/inst/jacobs.m#l141) (from the optim package), [plotpdb](http://hg.code.sf.net/p/octave/pdb/file/ac4b11313810/inst/plotpdb.m#l54) (from the pdb package), or [pq_lo_view](http://hg.code.sf.net/p/octave/database/file/5e97c8b9e595/inst/pq_lo_view.m#l34) (from the database package).

Answer (score 2):

```
[pid, msg] = fork();

if pid
  # wait child to complete
  disp(["waiting for ", num2str(pid)]);
  waitpid(pid);
else
  # do work in child process
endif
```

I think the documentation assumes you're familiar with the UNIX `fork` model.